# Can I unwrap oracle XMLType or at least get XML from Weblogic generated wrapper class?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, weblogic, wrapper, xmltype

Weblogic wraps objects on connections. I am aware I can just disable the wrapping, but I would like to have some code that would work with it enabled.

The XMLType is the payload of the JMS message queue. The listener that does receives the messages and then throws and expection looks like

```
  public Object fromMessage(Message message) throws .. {
    AQjmsAdtMessage aqMessage = (AQjmsAdtMessage) message;
    Object payload = aqMessage.getAdtPayload();
    return handler.getXmlContent((XMLType) payload);
}
```

If I do not do anything, I get the class cast exception. The actual type of the received payload is of the `weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.WrapperSQLXML_oracle_xdb_XMLType` on Weblogic if the wrapping is enabled, while it is XMLType if the wrapping is disabled, or while running on Tomcat.

I was unable to find much documentation about the `weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.WrapperSQLXML_oracle_xdb_XMLType` class, but I found it has the `unwrap`(Class cls) method that I can invoke. The code below works:

```
Method unwrap = payload.getClass().getMethod("unwrap", Class.class);
XMLTypeIntf xmlType = (XMLTypeIntf) unwrap.invoke(payload, XMLTypeIntf.class);
```

Unfortunately I have no clue what to do with the obtained `XMLTypeIntf` interface, how to convert it to the true XMLType, Document or at least a raw XML stream. `XMLTypeIntf` extends `java.sql.SQLXML, oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleOpaque` and `oracle.sql.ORAData` so could theoretically provide the content, but everything I tried to call so far from these inherited interfaces appears to be just unimplemented stubs. Does it have *anything* that works and could provide XML?

I also tried to call `WrapperSQLXML_oracle_xdb_XMLType.unwrap(XMLType)` but this also throws and exception - "must be an interface".

Is there any way to get a usable XML object or content from WrapperSQLXML_oracle_xdb_XMLType object?

Comment: What are you actually doing when you get the initial error? Showing your code and the data you're using might be helpful, along with the result of running your query directly against the database.

Comment: I do not run the direct query, it is the JMS message listener that uses Oracle Advanced Queuing. I have extended the question to more code now.